# A question on order unbounded sequences in Banach lattices

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $E$ be a Banach lattice. It is well-known that every norm convergent sequence in $E$ admits an order convergent subsequence and hence admits an order bounded subsequence. But it seems that a norm convergent sequence in $E$  needs not be order bounded. Is there any counterexample?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if I got the precise meaning of "order bounded"; however e.g. in $L^1$ it is easy to find sequences $f_k\to 0$ in norm, and not dominated in $L^1$, e.g. $\chi_{[k,k+1]}/k$. (It is also true that for a convergent sequence $f_k$ there exists $g\in L^1$ and a subsequence $f_{k_j}$ such that $|f_{k_j}(x)|\le g(x)$, but not the whole sequence in general)

Comment: Why is  the sequence $(f_{k})_{k}$ not dominated in $L^{1}$?

Comment: Because $\sup_{k\ge1}{\chi_{[k,k+1)}(x)\over k}=1/\lfloor x\rfloor$ for any $x\ge1$